# Can I 'embed' an iframe into a jsp so that the iframe height is automatically adjusted according to its contents?

Tags: html, jsp, iframe

how can I embed an `iframe` into a jsp so that the top iframe acts like a row in a table and the bottom iframe acts as a second row in the table and the cell size is adjusted automatically to fit the contents in the iframe? By doing this, there won't be an internal iframe scroll bar appearing when the iframe content is more than the height of the iframe?

I tried to put an iframe in a table cell but.. that's syntax error...

The reason I want to use iframe instead of table is that I would like to embed my another application into the page. Thank you very much in advance.

Edit: Also, the reason that I don't use frameset is that the frame will occupy the fix amount of browser viewing space, but I want it to be able to be scrolled off the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a post I found that might help u. 
http://www.Kaali.Co.Uk/index.pl?art=94

Comment: thanks. you can always contact me for any kind of help at nilanjanchakraborty87@gmail.com / +91-8013689668